# How to dynamically create select options when using materialize css

Tags: javascript, html, materialize

I am reposing my question as I was able to solve some part of it and only need help on certain point.

I am able to populate rest of the table content dynamically except the `<select>` elements.

Because I am using Materialize css I am getting trouble creating it.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){


google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(getLeaveRosterData).loadRoster();
 var elems = document.querySelectorAll('select');
 var instances = M.FormSelect.init(elems);

});

let weeksArray = ["sunday", "monday", "tuesday", "wednesday", "thursday", "friday", "saturday"];

dataArray.forEach(function(ele) 
{
  const tableRow = document.createElement("tr");

  var agentTD = document.createElement("td");
  agentTD.setAttribute("id", "agent"+ ele);
  var t = document.createTextNode(ele);
  agentTD.appendChild(t);

  var w1TD = document.createElement("td");
  w1TD.appendChild(createDropdown("w1-" + ele));

   // create td elements with unique ids
  var w2TD = document.createElement("td");
  w2TD.appendChild(createDropdown("w2-" + ele));

  tableRow.appendChild(agentTD);
  tableRow.appendChild(w1TD);
  tableRow.appendChild(w2TD);
  tbody.appendChild(tableRow);

});
function createDropdown(id) {
  //create a radio button
  var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
  var select = document.createElement('select');
  select.setAttribute("id", id);
  weeksArray.forEach(function (day) {
    select.options.add( new Option(day, day));
  });
  fragment.appendChild(select);
  return fragment;
}
```

My select elements are day names.["sunday", "monday", "tuesday", "wednesday", "thursday", "friday", "saturday"]. Any suggestion is welcomed.

[image]

Comment: "I am getting trouble creating it", What is the specific problem?

Comment: it does not show up in the table.

Comment: Are you initialising the select after dynamically adding the options? Also, for such a small finite, unchanging list of options - surely easier to hardcode them? Actually I think I don’t understand your problem.

Comment: Yes its initialized. please check I have edited my Question. I did not wanted to post long code lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A note on Materialize CSS neding "initalization": https://materializecss.com/select.html

**Initialization**

You must initialize the select element as shown below. In addition, you will need a separate call for any dynamically generated select elements your page generates.

```
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('select');
    var instances = M.FormSelect.init(elems, options);
  });

  // Or with jQuery

  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('select').formSelect();
  });
```

You can either use the above code to do them all in bulk, or target each added select more individually.

---

The code you posted is missing some references to make it testable, but I've added those, but essentially does what you're looking for as-is. You can run this in-browser here to confirm the select lists are rendered.

```js
let weeksArray = ["sunday", "monday", "tuesday", "wednesday", "thursday", "friday", "saturday"];

const dataArray = ['example 1', 'example 2'];
const tbody = document.querySelector('tbody');

dataArray.forEach(function(ele) 
{
  const tableRow = document.createElement("tr");

  var agentTD = document.createElement("td");
  agentTD.setAttribute("id", "agent"+ ele);
  var t = document.createTextNode(ele);
  agentTD.appendChild(t);

  var w1TD = document.createElement("td");
  w1TD.appendChild(createDropdown("w1-" + ele));

   // create td elements with unique ids
  var w2TD = document.createElement("td");
  w2TD.appendChild(createDropdown("w2-" + ele));

  tableRow.appendChild(agentTD);
  tableRow.appendChild(w1TD);
  tableRow.appendChild(w2TD);
  tbody.appendChild(tableRow);

});
function createDropdown(id) {
  //create a radio button
  var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
  var select = document.createElement('select');
  select.setAttribute("id", id);
  weeksArray.forEach(function (day) {
    select.options.add( new Option(day, day));
  });
  fragment.appendChild(select);
  return fragment;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: it works normally when I do not use materialize css. but if you will use materialize css it stops working.

Comment: See https://materializecss.com/select.html, you need to "initalize" your dynamically added selects in that case.

Comment: I have initialized this as you can see in my question. `var elems = document.querySelectorAll('select');
 var instances = M.FormSelect.init(elems);`

Comment: That only happens on dom load (initial page load). It needs to happen every time you add a new control to the page.

Comment: Ohh what an observation. You are right Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: You may edit your answer so that I could give it thumbs up.